# Java Mail writeTo and read back gives Illegal semicolon error

Tags: java, email

I am using java to get a mail message and persist that message to a file. When I go to read the file back in I am getting an javax.mail.internet.AddressException

Below is the code I use to write the message

```
Properties mailProps = System.getProperties();
mailProps.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
Session session = null;
Folder inbox = null;
Store store = null;
Message[] messages = null;

try {
    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(mailProps, null);
    store = session.getStore("imaps");

    store.connect(config.getMailHost(), config.getMailUserId(), config.getMailPasswd());

    inbox = store.getFolder("inbox");
    inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE); // Folder.READ_ONLY
    logger.info("Total Messages found on Host: <{}>", inbox.getMessageCount());
    logger.info("Total Unread Messages on Host: <{}>", inbox.getUnreadMessageCount());

    messages = inbox.getMessages();

    for (Message currMessage : messages) {

        File mailFile = buildMailFileName();
        currMessage.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(mailFile));
    }
}
```

I can see the file is created and contains the following line:

> To: Name@domain.com;

When I go to read the file back in I get the following error:

**javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Illegal semicolon, not in group in string 'Name@domain**.

Here is the code I use to read the file:

```
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(mailProps, null);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(mailFile);
MimeMessage mime = new MimeMessage(null, fis);
Address[] addresses = mime.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO);
```

Comment: Where is the code you use to write the mail message? A semicolon is not valid, e-mail addresses are separated by comma's (don't be fooled by Outlook) and can't be at the end of a line in any case.

Comment: myMailMessage.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(mailFile)); - That is the only code I use to write the message. where myMailMessage is a javax.mail.Message object.

Comment: How do you create `myMailMessage`?

Answer (score 4):

Semicolon is not allowed as the separator for email addresses, use commas instead!

Answer (score 2):

The [InternetAddress](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#parse(java.lang.String)) class that is used to parse email addresses uses comma not semicolon
So when you are writing to the file change `semicolon` with `comma` as a result  you will have `Name@domain.com,` instead of `Name@domain.com;`

Comment: I figured that out... how to take a java Mail message and write it with a comma instead of semicolon?

Comment: @Ben you can set it like this message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));